# SFTP into server - can server view my local files?

Tags: file, server, sftp

Scenario:

1) I SFTP into a remote server through the Tor network.

a) I do not have physical access to the server

b) I do have root access to the server

2) I am able to view the local files present on the server.

Question:

3) Is the server able to view the local files present on my computer? Assume the files are encrypted but have been decrypted when SFTP'ing. (HDD, SSD, USB etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it can't. Unless you are using a rigged SFTP client program.

The FTP protocol is clear and precise in what are the roles for client and server - and the server can't issue commands to the client at all.

You could be tricked into issuing commands to send list of your files in a PUT command to the server, but is hard to imagine.

Or, if you are using an SFTP client program you have no control over, and was issued by the party you don't trust, this client might be rigged to send the server computer information about your local computer by other means than via the SFTP protocol. If you are using an independent SFTP client with a known good origin, this can't happen, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to the server, with the help of WinSCP or MobaXterm you should be able to access the files from your local machine, you can drag and drop the files from local machine to server vice vera(assuming you are accessing from windows op)